# Reading in C using fscanf multiple values

Tags: c, scanf

From a text file of the following format:

```
Name Surname ID Address
Name Surname ID Address
Name Surname ID Address
```

I need to extract each one and put it in a variable.

I tried the following two methods:

```
while(fscanf(fp, "%s,%s,%d,%s\n", name2,surname2,&id2,address2) != EOF){
    printf("Name: %s, Surname: %s, ID: %d, Address: %s\n",
        &name2, &surname2, &id2, &address2);
}
```

Which gives me the wrong results it only reads one word for each line so the result is something like this:

```
Name: Name Surname:@,a ID:2272012 Address: ?"
Name: Surname Surname:@,a ID:2272012 Address: ?"
Name: ID Surname:@,a ID:2272012 Address: ?"
Name: Address Surname:@,a ID:2272012 Address: ?"
```

And the other method I used was:

```
while(fscanf(fp, "%s,%s,%d,%s\n", name2,surname2,&id2,address2) == 4){
    printf("Name: %s, Surname: %s, ID: %d, Address: %s\n",
        &name2, &surname2, &id2, &address2);
}
```

Which reads nothing and nothing happens.

The file I'm reading from is .dat and it's for an assignment and so can only use .dat.

Comment: Can we see the input data file contents?

Comment: Beware that using the string specifier without a width specifier it's not really safe, it's almost like `gets`.

Comment: there is no comma between fields in your input file ? Because you are using comma `,` as delimiter between fields in the `scanf`

Answer (score 2):

- You shouldn't have commas in the format string unless there are commas in the data, which you don't show.
- If any of the fields contain spaces, this won't work since `%s` will stop.
- You need to show more of your input .dat file.
- It's often better to read a whole line using `fgets()`, and *then* worry about parsing it.

Answer (score 2):

You state that your text file is in the format:

```
string<space>string<space>numeric<space>string<newline>
```

If that is accurate your format string has to match exactly:

```
strings
 |  |  numeric
 |  |  |  +-----string
 |  |  |  | +---newline
 V  V  V  V V
"%s %s %d %s\n"
   ^  ^  ^
   |  |  |
   spaces
```

This assums each `string` field is a single block of ASCII values, no spaces/tabs etc. Your code is missing how the variables are defined, presumably it's something like:

```
char name2[100] = {0};
char surname2[100] = {0};
int id2 = 0;
char address2[100] = {0};
```

In which case you don't need the `&` before the names of these in your `fscanf` string. So given an input file of:

> firt ast 1234 somebody@something.com
>   sec but 22352 goo@gle.com
>   thir haha 9999 nice@lly.com

And the above variable declairactions, the following code:

```
FILE * fp;
fp = fopen("test.txt", "r");
while(fscanf(fp, "%s %s %d %s\n", name2, surname2, &id2, address2) == 4) 
    printf("name: %s %s, id: %d, address %s\n", name2, surname2, id2, address2);

fclose(fp);
```

Correctly reads/displays the values.

Answer (score 1):

First, remove the `&` from variables in the `printf`

```
printf("Name: %s, Surname: %s, ID: %d, Address: %s\n",
        name2, surname2, id2, address2);
```

If the separoter between field in your input txt file is comma `,`

```
Name,Surname , ID ,Address
Name ,Surname,ID,Address
Name,Surname,ID,Address
```

Then use the following string format in the `fscanf`

```
while(fscanf(fp, " %[^, ] , %[^, ] , %d , %[^\n]", name2,surname2,&id2,address2) != EOF){
    printf("Name: %s, Surname: %s, ID: %d, Address: %s\n",
        name2, surname2, id2, address2);
}
```

If the separoter between fields in your input txt file is space

```
Name Surname ID Address
Name Surname ID Address
Name Surname ID Address
```

Then use the following string format in the `fscanf`

```
while(fscanf(fp, " %s %s %d %[^\n]", name2,surname2,&id2,address2) != EOF){
    printf("Name: %s, Surname: %s, ID: %d, Address: %s\n",
        name2, surname2, id2, address2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while(fscanf(fp, "%s,%s,%d,%s\n", name2,surname2,&id2,address2) != EOF){
    printf("Name: %s, Surname: %s, ID: %d, Address: %s\n",
        &name2, &surname2, &id2, &address2);
}
```

I think this is where the error lies:

it should be:

```
while(fscanf(fp, "%s,%s,%d,%s\n", name2,surname2,&id2,address2) != EOF){
    printf("Name: %s, Surname: %s, ID: %d, Address: %s\n",
        name2, surname2, id2, address2);
}
```